# Addition or removal to SynchronizedMap, and synchronized blocks

Tags: java, android, collections, aws-sdk

I am using AWS Android SDK to uploading image files to an S3 bucket. I do cropping operation in a thread which starts transfer of image file after cropping is done. I save all TransferObserver instances in a Map as defined and initialized below:

```
private Map<String, TransferObserver> transferObservers;

A() {
    transferObservers = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, TransferObserver>());
}

public void add(Image image) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Cropping
            ...
            TransferObserver uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload(key, new File(localFilePath));
            uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            photoTransferObservers.put(image.getPath(), uploadObserver);
        }
    }
}
```

The image can be deleted so thus its entry in the map:

```
public void deleteTransferRecord(String key) {
    transferObservers.remove(key);
}
```

There is also another function that returns overall process of uploads:

```
private void notifyListeners() {
    int completedUploadCount = 0;
    for (TransferObserver transferObserver : transferObservers.values()) {
        if (transferObserver.getState() == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
            completedUploadCount++;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I got an exception -which I didn't take note- about removal attempt during iteration on `transferObservers`. How should I update my code to prevent any concurrency issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could synchronize over `transferObservers` wherever you access it (whether addition, removal, or read).  At that point you don't need the `Collections.synchronizedMap`.

Or, a simpler solution may be to simply copy the values before iterating in `notifyListeners`.  That way removals or adds to the transfer observers won't cause a `ConcurrentModificationException` while iterating.

```
private void notifyListeners() {
    int completedUploadCount = 0;
    List<TransferObserver> observers = new ArrayList<>(transferObservers.values());
    for (TransferObserver transferObserver : observers) {
        if (transferObserver.getState() == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
            completedUploadCount++;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```